# Restarting a program with monit

Tags: monitoring, monit

Hopefully someone can help me out with this:
I am running a game server that crashes with a segfault every 3 hours, I am trying to get a restart script working but I'm a complete noob when it comes to Linux(Debian)
Working directory is:
***/home/(username)/workspace/MMOCoreORB/bin***
To start Program:
***./core3***
It starts in terminal and runs until the 3 hour crash...
At the moment I've installed monit but I have no clue what to do next....
I copied the Apache2 restart section in the monit config and made changes to run the program I need but not sure I did it right either...

server.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
 case $1 in
    start)
       echo $$ > server.pid;
    cd /home/user/workspace/MMOCoreORB/bin/
       exec ./core3
       ;;
     stop) 
       kill $(cat server.pid);
       rm server.pid
       ;;
     *) 
       echo "usage: server {start|stop}" ;;
 esac
 exit 0
```

monit config:

```
  GNU nano 2.2.4           File: /etc/monit/monitrc                             
###############################################################################
## Monit control file
###############################################################################
##
## Comments begin with a '#' and extend through the end of the line. Keywords
## are case insensitive. All path's MUST BE FULLY QUALIFIED, starting with '/'.
##
## Below you will find examples of some frequently used statements. For
## information about the control file and a complete list of statements and
## options, please have a look in the Monit manual.
##
##
###############################################################################
## Global section
###############################################################################
##
## Start Monit in the background (run as a daemon):
#
         set daemon  120           # check services at 2-minute intervals
```

Comment: Please show your Monit configuration.

Comment: I edited my main post to show everything I have (see above)

Comment: Have you looked at all the examples here?  http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples